# KDE scroll speed is not proportional to wheel speed

Tags: kde, mouse-scroll

On KDE, each click in the mouse wheel results in some distance going up and down. If I scroll faster or slower, the same shift in the viewport is achieved.

Is there some way to scroll more when I scroll faster, like it is on the Mac?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that only the mouse pointer has the acceleration settings.

System Settings > Input Devices > Mouse

http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kdebase-workspace/kcontrol/mouse/index.html

There are wish reports:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/619403

The Xorg report seems to have a patch. So maybe the acceleration is soon available ? The latest comment is 2011-10-09.

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe that this is not a standard feature … I think Gnome has this. At least the report is active.

Comment: @queueoverflow Gnome never had this feature AFAIK.

Comment: So after many years, nothing really happened. Maybe Wayland bring some improvement.

Comment: [This is the new link for the XServer issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/issues/405) (reported by me originally, also my patch...), [this is the launchpad report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/619403), and [here is a similar report for lipinput in Wayland](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/7). I guess you could help with your vote on the issue. Or with an updated patch for libinput.

Answer (score 12):

This is a bug that has been known for nearly ten years, and the community, for whatever reason, has intentionally ignored it. The developers who have made an attempt to fix this appear to get frustrated and quit. This appears to be most common in wireless or optical mice produced by Microsoft. That might have something to do with their choice to ignore a bug that end-users have been reporting for a decade. There is no setting for scroll speed in either Gnome or KDE. I think this is more of an issue with the X window system than either window manager. There's a way to fix this permanently, in Firefox, only. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7416951

Otherwise, try unplugging the mouse's wireless dongle from your USB port, leave it for a few seconds, then plug it back in. Seems to work.

Having the same issue here. I'm learning that a scroll wheel is a luxury... It makes me miss the old Macintosh.