# Can I enable OS X-style mouse wheel scrolling (not natural scrolling)

Tags: mouse, mouse-scroll

This is the way that Mac OS scrolling with a boring old handheld mouse works (as opposed to fancy soap bar and multitouch mice): The more and the faster you scroll, the further the mouse scrolling goes.

For instance, if I scroll one little tick on the mouse, the window scrolls a tiny amount. However, if I scroll twice in fast succession, the window scrolls a small amount once and then a faster amount the next time, etc.

Ubuntu has boring old pure linear scrolling. Is there nay way I can enable the Mac OS scrolling?

Comment: Ubuntu **13.10** has natural scrolling in the **System Settings > Mouse**

Comment: Looks like it just does not work, see [question here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81356/kde-scroll-speed-is-not-proportional-to-wheel-speed/81416?noredirect=1#comment624202_81416).

Comment: A more recent question is also asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228224/kde-mouse-scrolling-acceleration).

Answer (score 0):

This feature is often referred to as mouse scroll acceleration, or mouse wheel acceleration.
Unfortunately, this feature is not implemented yet.

[Here is the corresponding XServer issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/issues/405) (reported by me originally, also my patch...), [this is the launchpad report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/619403), and [here is a similar report for lipinput in Wayland](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/7).

I guess you could help with your vote on the issue. Or with an updated patch for libinput.

---

I implemented such a feature in user space [here (mouse-scroll-wheel-acceleration-userspace)](https://github.com/albertz/mouse-scroll-wheel-acceleration-userspace).
This will increase the scroll speed, or accelerate the scroll speed.
You would just run this in the background, with your preferred options.
The code is quite simple Python code, and should be easy to modify as well.

Answer (score -4):

There is software called NaturalScrolling.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zedtux/naturalscrolling`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install naturalscrolling`

Happy scrolling.

Comment: From the PPA description: "Use Natural Scrolling to reverse the direction of scrolling on your Linux." This is not what the OP asked for.