# KDE mouse scrolling acceleration

Tags: mouse, kde, mouse-scroll

Is there any settings regarding mouse scroll acceleration in KDE 5.67? (or if not , how to change it via `X` ?)
I have problem scrolling in `Dolphin` and specially `Okular` PDF viewer.

Thanks.

Comment: What version Of Ubuntu? Things appear to have changed quite a lot, plenty of tweaks in 16.04, to zilch in 19.10.

Comment: [This question is related/similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81356/kde-scroll-speed-is-not-proportional-to-wheel-speed).

Answer (score 2):

No, this feature is not implemented yet.

[Here is the corresponding XServer issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/issues/405) (reported by me originally, also my patch...), [this is the launchpad report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/619403), and [here is a similar report for lipinput in Wayland](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/-/issues/7).

I guess you could help with your vote on the issue. Or with an updated patch for libinput.

---

If you just want to have increased scrolling speed (by a constant factor, not accelerated/dynamic),
see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/255890/how-can-i-adjust-the-mouse-scroll-speed),
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285689/increase-mouse-wheel-scroll-speed)
or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030678/speeding-up-the-mouse-wheel-in-ubuntu-18-04).

---

I implemented such a feature in user space [here (mouse-scroll-wheel-acceleration-userspace)](https://github.com/albertz/mouse-scroll-wheel-acceleration-userspace).
This will increase the scroll speed, or accelerate the scroll speed.
You would just run this in the background, with your preferred options.
The code is quite simple Python code, and should be easy to modify as well.